# Deploy Angular 4 IIS error "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."

Tags: angular, iis, angular-ui-router, web-config, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy an Angular 4 web site on an IIS server and I'm getting this error

"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."

My URL that I'm using is http://domain/LpPortal2/login/client and the "client" is not an actual component in my Angular project, it's for my login page to know which logo and colors to show on the page. Here is the code in my app.routes.ts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login/:clientCode',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
...
```

Here is my web.config in case for your information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" 
type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
     <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
       <defaultDocument>
           <files>
               <remove value="index.php" />
               <remove value="default.aspx" />
               <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
               <remove value="index.htm" />
               <remove value="Default.asp" />
               <remove value="Default.htm" />
            </files>
       </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812148/angular-4-403-forbidden-on-route-parameter-with-iis

Answer (score 4):

So the issue was when I built my app I needed to add --base-ref /my-domain-name/ like below:

```
ng build -env=dev --base-href /LPPortal2/
```

Plus I needed to update the rewrite to

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/LPPortal2" />
```

Those 2 things fixed my 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Run the IDE as Administrator  to  open the Angula folder and it will work and you could save your work as I had the same problem and running Visual Studio Code(You can use any type of your favorite IDE) as administrator solved the problem.