# Angular 4 403 Forbidden on route parameter with IIS

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, iis-6

I deployed my Angular project to our dev environment using IIS Version 6.1 SP1 and I'm getting 403 Forbidden error on my route parameter. In my URL, the "client" is not a component but a route parameter. The project works perfectly fine on my localhost, the issue is only when I pushed the code to our development environment.

[image]
Here is my code in app.routes.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
       path: '',
       redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'login/:licenseeCode',
    component: LoginComponent

},
...
```

Comment: I don't think the Angular routing is enough information to tell you where or what the problem is. That looks fine; you don't even have any guards that could be blocking people from viewing a component. And if it's different between local and production environments, it's clearly something *outside* the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you deployed to a folder (NOT ROOT) you might need to adjust your

```
<base href="/FOLDER_WHERE_YOU_DEPLOYED/" />
```

also try adding this to your config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/FOLDER_WHERE_YOU_DEPLOYED/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I just found. When I built my project I had to add --base-href /LPPortal2/ and modified the rewrite accordingly. Thanks